# GRANT permissions to wildcard database but specific table(s)

Tags: mysql, database, sql-grant

So, I know I can wildcard a database for all tables.  For instance if I wanted to grant select to a user for all tables in matching databases, I could:

```
GRANT SELECT
ON 'databasesprefix%'.*
TO testuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'testpasswd';
```

However if I wanted to grant UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT to teh user on all matching databases but only for a specific table, the following doesn't work:

```
GRANT UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT
ON 'databasesprefix%'.specifictable
TO testuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'testpasswd';
```

Is there a way to doe this in SQL?  or will I have to script this externally?

Comment: Why do you have the same table in every database?  This suggests a very denormalised schema, which may well be a poor design choice.

Comment: Seperate silos for the same application across different customers.  I have no control over this design.  Just looking to add users with specific permissions.

Answer (score 1):

No.
There is no way to do it in MySQL.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

```
priv_level:
    *
  | *.*
  | db_name.*
  | db_name.tbl_name
  | tbl_name
  | db_name.routine_name
```

rtm :)

Comment: Yep, read the manual but couldn't definitively tell when I read it  whether or not both database and table could be wildcarded since thh priv_level you quoted mentions neither the % or _ meta-character wildcards.  Thanks for clarifying.